# Display input label underneath input element

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to display a label underneath an input element like this form: http://www.appnitro.com/demo/view.php?id=7

I have been able to get the labels underneath, but using my current method I cant have multiple inputs on the same line like the form I linked to.

What is the best and cleanest way to do this?

Here's my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/6znGU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it by looking at the source of the example you gave. Put each `input` with its `label` into a `span` that has `float: left` set.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ab9hv/

And by the way, you can put the `input` inside the `label`, then you don't need the `for` attribute.

```
<span style="float: left;">
    <label><input type="text" name="fn"/>First</label>
</span>

<span style="float: left;">
    <label><input type="text" name="ln"/>Last</label>
</span>
```

New code: http://jsfiddle.net/QwDmr/

Comment: Thanks! Nice, neat and works perfectly.

Didn't know you could nest the input inside the labels like that. Is that proper html?

Comment: Yes, it is. What the specs say about the *for* attribute: *When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.* Doesn't work in IE6, though, but fails gracefully (just not clickable).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some divs. One div to make the row of inputs and labels, and a div for each pair inside the row so they can float without clearing the objects to the left and right of them. Using margin to space them.

```
<div class="rowOfFields">
    <div style="float:left">
          <input type="text" name="fn" id="" />
          <label for="fn">First</label>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
          <input type="text" name="ln" id="" />
          <label for="ln">Last</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or as you can see by looking at the example form you posted you can also use display: inline; instead of float: left;

Answer (score 0):

You had the solution in that example you gave. You need to wrap your `label` `input` combos into a `div` element and either left float them or make them in-line elements.

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6znGU/1/).

Hope this helps !